# How to Add Social Sharing Buttons on a static site?

Tags: html, share, static-site, social-media

I'm looking to Add social sharing buttons on a static which is having more than 500 Static Pages.

I can add manually but it's very tedious task so looking for an easy way to add.

Is there any Way to get the Permalinks of a Static Site Dynamically I'm thinking to pass it to the Sharing Code so that I can append the URL in the code if there is any way to add a piece of code automatically to all the pages it would be of great help.

Best Regards,
Arpit

Answer (score 0):

You manually have created 500 pages or using php to generate dynamically?
If it is generated dynamically, you can easily add social share plugin to every page.

HTML code for social share by social9.com
https://www.social9.com/get-free-social-share/
...Select "code your own" from the list for HTML Code.

Comment: 1) The link is broken
2) She's kind of right... Managing 500 static HTML pages manually isn't really going to get you anywhere. Have a look at [JBake](http://jbake.org).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

1. Use regular expressions in an IDE to find the right places and place the code in the replacing string.
2. If that's not enough powerful, then write a script, using e.g. Bash in Linux, or Groovy, or I would personally write a simple Java program leveraging the JSoup library.
3. Lastly, and I would recommend that most, give up maintaining the files manually, and switch to static site generating software, like [JBake](http://jbake.org).
   JBake can take your HTML pages and take their content as an input and re-generate the website through templates.